# How can I listen to mouse events of other processes

Tags: c#, windows-messages

Is it possible in C# to listen to mouse related windows messages sent to other windows in other processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a open source project in codeplex for that 
[Application and Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks .Net Libary in C#](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) 
If you want to do this yourself do some extra search on `Windows Hooks`
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks) article shows how

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at the [Codeplex Application and Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks library](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/)

> This library attaches to windows global hooks, tracks keyboard and mouse clicks and movement and raises common .NET events with KeyEventArgs and MouseEventArgs, so you can easily retrieve any information you need:
>   Mouse coordinates
>   Mouse buttons clicked
>   Mouse wheel scrolls
>   Key presses and releases
>   Special key states

From above links [Documentation](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/documentation):

> Before beginning it is important to know that hooking terms can and will be used interchangeably. Global hooks are also known as System, or System-Wide hooks, and will encompass the entire operating system. Application hooks are often called Local, because as the name implies, will only correspond to the single application which placed the hook (or a specific thread).

Answer (score 1):

There is no managed way to do this.
However, with Windows Api this is possible:

This should help you.

[C# - Capturing Windows Messages from a specific application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289321/c-sharp-capturing-windows-messages-from-a-specific-application)

It would be a good start to capture WM_MOUSEMOVE
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx

But there are other mouse related window messages, too.

Comment: The article is about receiving broadcast events and not intercepting internal events in another application, which requires a DLL injected into the other process can can't be done in Native C#.